# Handling of character references in an embedded SVG's script tags

Tags: javascript, html, svg, xss

This is a xss script:

```
<svg><script>&#x61;&#x6c;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x31;&#x29;</script></svg>
```

The code between `<script>` tags will be translated to `alert(1)` by the browser and executed.

But if I don't use a `<svg>` tag the code won't be translated to script. 
Can anyone tell me why this happens? How does `<svg>` tag work?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a  fine question.

Comment: Confirmed this in Chrome, seems like a weird by-effect of how the DOM is being parsed. Highly doubt some kind of 'standards' are involved here.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Everything here is explicitly defined by the XML and html 5 standards.

Comment: Yes, I get that and I knew that. I'm just not entirely convinced (from your answer either) that it's expected behaviour when a script document is embedded in an SVG document embedded in HTML. That means in the end it's handled by the HTML parser, which explicitly disallows character references in script as you correctly state in your first sentence. Therefore it seems like an unfortunate "open to interpretation" by-effect that in this case the SVG handling takes precedence in implementations over HTML's explicit prohibition, whilst disallowed usually prevails over allowed.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I've expanded my answer to cover what the html 5 specification says about parsing SVG within html

Comment: But that's not entirely conclusive either is it? That line's intention seems to be to leave subelements like `<rect>` to the SVG specifications, not introduce a conflict in the handling of an element that is specified **both** in HTML and [in SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html#ScriptElement). I'm still tempted to say that, as the HTML spec explicitly forbids this in `script` tags for security reasons, it exposes a gap in the specs where it doesn't define whether the containing document's standards or the containing subelement's standards take precedence. <...continued...>

Comment: And thus, it leaves a loophole for malevolent scripters to circumvent virus/malware scanners to introduce undetected scripting code in HTML documents as the authors of such products expect character references to be ignored in HTML documents anyway. From what I read in the specs, that behaviour is neither intended nor conclusively defined. And as the scripts in SVG are not sandboxed to the SVG-subelement, I see lots of potential issues arising from the current implementation. HTML's script parsing state exists for a reason, and this is a plain bypass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#script-data-state) within script tags is explicitly disallowed by the HTML parser according to the HTML 5 specification.

HTML5 has a [separate script parsing mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#script-data-state) as one of a number of tokenisation modes that vary with context. Script parsing does not allow character references, some of the other parsing modes do.

SVG is based on XML where the rules are much simpler and more straightforward. Basically character references are allowed anywhere because there [aren't different context sensitive parsing modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-entexpand).

For SVG in html, the HTML specification [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#svg)

> The svg element from the SVG namespace falls into the embedded content, phrasing content, and flow content categories for the purposes of the content models in this specification.

In other words, parse all SVG text as phrasing content. All SVG is a single custom tokenisation mode for the HTML 5 parser.

Comment: Please check my new answer  :)   As said, your answer is afaics completely correct, just not the full explanation of this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

As I wasn't really satisfied with the other answer's citations on the reasoning behind this behaviour I escalated this 'issue' to the [WHATWG mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2015Jun/0089.html), as it does present some possible (albeit small) security loopholes. To quote Ian Hickson (chief editor of the HTML5 standard at W3C) [verbatim](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2015Jun/0090.html):

> It's not great, but it is intentional. Within `<svg>` and `<math>` blocks,
>   we  use the "foreign content" parsing mode wherein parsing is much
>   more  similar to legacy XML parsing than legacy HTML parsing:
>
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing-main-inforeign
>
> Note in particular that the special behaviour for `<script>` here
>   doesn't  include changing the tokeniser mode, like it would in
>   non-foreign content.

So while Robert's answer is essentially a collection of correct quotes pertaining to standalone HTML5 and SVG content, there is a specific separate section regarding the *parsing* of 'foreign content' explaining this behaviour. And Ian agrees it's not really a perfect solution, but honestly I can't think of one either that is compatible both with "semi-SGML" and XML parsing.